# Griffith's vector potential identity

Tags: electrostatics

I am working through some problems in Griffith's text "Introduction to Electrodynamics", and am having some trouble with an identity he uses. In Example 2.7 (and many times throughout the book) he says something along the lines of (with a sphere of radius $R$ constant and $z$ varying either inside or outside the sphere)

$$
\sqrt{(R-z)^2} = z-R
$$

for $z>R$, and for points $z<R$,

$$
\sqrt{(R-z)^2} = R-z
$$

I'm guessing this is something simple but I don't see it. I thought about making an argument that the overall term is negative in one case and lets me pull a minus sign outside $\sqrt{(R-z)^2} = \sqrt{(-(z-R))^2} = \sqrt{(z-R)^2} = z-R$ but I don't think this is right, I could do it for either.

Comment: $\sqrt{(R-z)^2} = | R -z |$ by definition. Now consider the two cases.

Answer (score 2):

There is no mysterious "vector potential identity" involved. As the square root is supposed to be a positive distance, you have to take the appropriate sign of the square root when R-z or z-R is positive.

PS: In example 2.7, Griffiths points this out explicitely himself!